# RStudio environment data.frame row count

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

I deal with large datasets frequently. Unfortunately, RStudio IDE's environment shows row count of data.frame like `156212811` and it'll be really useful if it shows in readable notation (like `156,212,811`).

Is there any way how I can force it to use commas in row count?

Attached screenshot for reference

[image]

Comment: It's an interesting thought. The bigger picture is how to customize how objects are displayed in the environment pane, not just how to add commas here. Though the output looks similar to that of (say) `dplyr::glimpse(...)`, that is likely just a coincidence. My suggestion is put in an issue at https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues, both with a *"can I add commas"* (in case that is really easy) and *"how to customize the environment pane"* (in case they have already discussed/planned mechanisms for a more generic solution).